# envsubst a yaml file that uses identation

Tags: shell-script

This is a kubernetes yaml config map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: $CONFIG_NAME
  namespace: processing
data:
  configuration.json: |
    {
      "test" : $TESTOBJECT
    }
```

And the `$TESTOBJECT` is a json object example like

```
{
  "sample1":"sample1",
  "sample2":"sample2"
}
```

The way I try to solve it is to extract the object using jq and then inject it with envsubst. The problem is that identation is wrong doing it like this

```
#!/bin/bash
export TESTOBJECT=$(jq .formats configuration.json)
envsubst '$TESTOBJECT' < "configuration.yml" > "configuration2.yml"
```

How can I fix the indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: Use the `-c` (`--compact-output`) option of *jq*, giving you a single-line document.

Method 2: Convert the whole `configuration.yml` file to JSON, use *jq* to substitute the variable in a JSON-compatible way, convert it back to YAML.

```
yaml2json configuration.yaml \
  | jq --slurpfile obj configuration.json \
    '(.data | .["configuration.json"]) = ({test: $obj[0] | .formats} | tojson)' \
  | json2yaml > configuration2.yaml
```

Method 3: Use a programming language with its own YAML and JSON support:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json, yaml
with open("configuration.yml", "r") as fh:
    yconf = yaml.load(fh)
with open("configuration.json", "r") as fh:
    jconf = json.load(fh)
jconf = {"test": jconf["formats"]}
yconf["data"]["configuration.json"] = json.dumps(jconf)
with open("configuration2.yml", "w") as fh:
    yaml.dump(yconf, stream=fh)
```